# Determine what Application assembly is needed

Tags: wpf, vb.net, reference, .net-assembly

There are 2 projects. Both are WPF Applications. 
[image: Application error]

**Application 1**: Just serves an Intercommunication with an external **Hardware**. For that, there are some public shared classes in the Application root class:

```
Public Shared Log As New clsLog
Public Shared NavigationObjectContainer As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
```

The **second project** is mainly the **GUI** and also uses some public shared classes in the Application root class:

```
Public Shared Nav As New clsNavigationHelper
```

Now, the second project (GUI) takes a reference to project 1 (Hardware) and shows the following error:

> Der Typeninitialisierer für "TB_HyperTerminal.Application" hat eine
>   Ausnahme verursacht. It's German but it means, that the Application
>   object in Class 1 (Hardware) is not able to find all shared classes
>   (like the clsLog and the NavigationObjectContainer).

InnerException

> {"Das Objekt des Typs "FSCANT3.Application" kann nicht in Typ
>   "TB_HyperTerminal.Application" umgewandelt werden."}

My question is how to solve this to get the **correct assemblies** and the correct **Application** object for each project.

When searching for the reason, I've renamed the class of project 2 (Hardware) to TBHApplication and project 1 is still called Application. No we can see why casting is not possible:
[image: Application casting]

Comment: Exception message is actually "The type initializer for 'TB_HyperTerminal.Application' threw an exception". This means that the static constructor for TB_HyperTerminal.Application failed. You should check inner exception for details.

Comment: Inner Exception added. Hope that helps more to find any solution.

Comment: FSCANT3.Application and TB_HyperTerminal.Application are different types that cannot be converted one another. Somewhere your application tries to convert a FSCANT3.Application instance to a TB_HyperTerminal.Application instance. And that is probably the static consturctor (Shared Sub New()) of TB_HyperTerminal.Application. If you can post some code it would help to figure out.

Comment: You've got too many types named "Application".  Including the one WPF uses.  Pick another name.

Comment: "Application" is set as default by WPF Visual Studio. Or I missunderstand how to "rename Application".

Answer (score 0):

Are there any dependent assemblies of Application 1 that you do not copy to the output directory of the second project ?

Update after discussing in the comments below.

As I understand your issue, you'd like app1 to be able to use methods from app2.
To do this, you need a common interface between your 2 applications. Create a 3rd project (of type 'class library') containing e.g. an interface that defines all the methods needed by app 1 and implemented by app2. Both app1 and app2 will reference this new DLL. You can implement this interface in your app2 application object and then app1 can cast the current application object to this interface type and call the methods.
I am not sure that I understand how app1 can then work in standalone-mode, however (Is this needed ? If not, shouldn't app1 be a class library too ?).

Please note that using application classes for this communication is a bit peculiar. The usual way is to use an IoC container or simply a property in app1 where app2 can set the implementation of the interface.

Comment: No, the assemblies are not the problem. all are there. just the namespace of "Application" is the same in Project 1 as it is in Project 2. That is by default on WPF project. But I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: The full name of a type includes its namespace AND the assembly it is defined in, so I don't think that you have an issue with the Application classes. What does the static constructor do and need ?

Comment: I will add a screenshot.... In VB.Net (similar in C#) uses the Global.System.Windows.Application.Current to cast it into the Application class.

Comment: If you do this in Application1, it will NOT work, as it will return the application object of project 2 (whatever its name).

Comment: I know that it does not work. But how to get it work? Because the namespace Application is given by DotNet not by myself.

Comment: I have too much to write in a comment. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim AppInfo As Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AssemblyInfo = GetApplicationInfo()


    Private Function GetApplicationInfo() As Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AssemblyInfo
        Dim ret As Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AssemblyInfo = Nothing
        Try
            Dim asm As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly
            ret = New Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AssemblyInfo(Global.System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return ret
    End Function


 Private Function GetApplication() As Global.System.Windows.Application
        Dim ret As Global.System.Windows.Application = Nothing
        Try
            ret = CType(Global.System.Windows.Application.Current, Global.System.Windows.Application)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return ret
    End Function
```